# Play sound in inner speaker

Tags: android, media-player, android-audiomanager, speaker

I am working on calling application, i want to play sound in caller device in inner speaker.

Here is my code,

```
mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
            audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
            audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
            mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            mMediaPlayer.start();
```

I tested it in Samsung galaxy s5, Moto g3 and assus Zenfone5 but its works only in samsung galaxy S5

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you don't need the following two strings:

> audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
>   audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);